# How to call FileIO.Write.via(Contextful, Contextful) in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-beam, parquet

I'm using Apache Beam with Scala. To create new `ParquetIO.Sink` instances with the respective schemas for the different types of streaming data, I'm trying to call `.via(Contextful, Contextful)` on `FileIO.Write`. However, IntelliJ cannot find the [overloaded method that I'm trying to use](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.Write.html#via-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful-) and raises this error: `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'via'`.

```scala
FileIO
  .writeDynamic[String, DeserializedEvent]()
  .by(new UDFs.PartitionByEventName())
  .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
  .withNumShards(numShards)
  .withNaming(new UDFs.NameFiles())
  .via(
    Contextful.fn[DeserializedEvent, GenericRecord](
      new UDFs.EventToGenericRecord() // SerializableFunction[DeserializedEvent, String]
    ),
    Contextful.fn[String, ParquetIO.Sink](
      new UDFs.SinkParquet() // SerializableFunction[String, ParquetIO.Sink]
    )
  )
  .to(path)
```

What's the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala's type inference system and overload resolution system don't work together quite perfectly.  In this case, the overloads of the via() function are preventing type inference from working properly.  [Why does scala fail to compile when method is overloaded in a seemingly unrelated way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902409/why-does-scala-fail-to-compile-when-method-is-overloaded-in-a-seemingly-unrelate) has a good explanation of the problem.

In your case, you should just need to change the type params of the second Contextful.fn to [String, FileIO.Sink] to make it match the signature of the desired overload.

Comment: Before your answer, I fixed the problem by changing `ParquetIO.Sink` to `FileIO.Sink[GenericRecord]`, but I did not understand the reason behind the problem. Thanks for the link, it clarified the situation a bit.